# Error: Step implementation missing for: [step_definition] with cypress & Cucumber when using Scenario outline with example

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, cucumberjs, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have the following Cucumber BDD set up based on Cypress.io. The test runs fine when hard coding the value but failing when it is given in the "Scenario Outline with example' way. What am I missing?

*Error:*

[image]

*Feature file:*

[image]

*Step Def:*

[image]

*Version:*

Cypress 7.1.0:
cypress-cucumber-preprocessor: "^4.0.3",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all combinations, this (using regex) one worked.

```
When(/^keying the vessel identifier ([^"]*) on the search box$/, searchTerm => {
    Search.doSearch(searchTerm)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing it `{String}`, but instead it should be `{string}`, all lowercase. That should fix your issue.

```
When(/^keying the vessel identifier {string} on the search box$/, (vesselName) => {
    Search.doSearch(searchTerm)
});
```

Edit:

Please try this instead, removing the regex pattern and instead using double quotes to define your WHEN statement. If you are using a regex pattern, then I do not believe you are able to use `{string}` to define a string parameter in your step.

```
When("keying the vessel identifier {string} on the search box", (vesselName) => {
    Search.doSearch(searchTerm)
});
```

Comment: Thank you @TestK. The moment I post it, I realized and changed to lowercase but unfortunately, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Updated the answer, which should actually correct the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I have tried your solution (non-regex way) but still, I am getting the same error as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As always, the explanation is in the documentation.

If you use Cucumber expression {string}, then the string to be matched MUST be enclosed in quotes (double ou single).

Your given line in feature file should be like:

```
When keying the vessel identifier 'something' on the search box
```

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/   (Parameter types)

> {string} :     Matches single-quoted or double-quoted strings, for example "banana split" or 'banana split' (but not banana split). Only the text between the quotes will be extracted. The quotes themselves are discarded. Empty pairs of quotes are valid and will be matched and passed to step code as empty strings.